# CVXPY and CPLEX - What is this attribute error about?

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, cplex, cvxpy

I am trying to solve the Unit Commitment Problem (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming problem) using the CVXPY framework for modelling the problem and CPLEX for solving the problem.

When I run my code I get an
AttributeError: 'Problem' object has no attribute '_compute_once_is_mixed_integer'

And this is the error I mainly get:

AttributeError: 'Problem' object has no attribute '_compute_once_is_mixed_integer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a CPLEX-specific problem. A similar cvxpy issue was reported in github [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/600). In short:

> The stack trace makes it seem like the issue is with your code, not
>   CVXPY. In particular, it indicates that one of your constraints in
>   constrlist is a NumPy object.

If you comment out the following constraint:

```
# Spinning Reserve Constraint
sum(isOn[:, k] * P_MAX) >= Load[k] + SR[k]
```

Then, the solve is successful.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the solve is successful. Because I commented out the line you suggested and still get no solution. Previous to your suggestion, I did try something else, which is to change any instance of sum to cp.sum and I now get an error saying CPLEX failed. Now I did try using the CPLEX solver on another code which I know works with the ECOS solver and it also failed. Is there anything in particular I have to do to install and use CPLEX with CVXPY. I had simply installed it using pip install cplex. Now I need to use CPLEX not ECOS since this is a MIQP problem.

Comment: The problem is too big for the free CPLEX Community Edition. You will need to install the production version of CPLEX to solve this model.

Comment: If you qualify, you can get the fully unlocked version of CPLEX through the Academic Initiative program. See [this](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/blog/2019/07/04/cplex-optimization-studio-for-students-and-academics/) blog post for details.

Comment: I have been using the CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.10.0 (accessed through my University) to solve this exact problem in MATLAB. And when using MATLAB, I usually addpath for the cplex file in MATLAB. Not sure how this would apply if using CVXPY?

Comment: Just to note, I have solved this problem in MATLAB using CPLEX. I just wanted to see if I could do the same in PYthon

Comment: You can do the following to install the unlocked version of CPLEX: 1) `pip uninstall cplex`; 2) `cd <COSDIR>/cplex/python/VERSION/PLATFORM` (where <COSDIR> is the location you installed CPLEX Optimization Studio, VERSION is the version of Python you are using, and PLATFORM is something like `x86-64_linux`, or `x64_win64`); 3) then `pip install .`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Any suggestions for including the constraint I commented out: Spinning Reserve Constraint
sum(isOn[:, k] * P_MAX) >= Load[k] + SR[k]

Comment: Figured it out. Need to use cp.multiply instead of *.